# How to make this ActionListener completely re-draw JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String[] options = {"1","2","4","8","16","20","40","100","400"} ;
int[] optionsNum = {1,2,4,8,16,20,40,100,400};
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(options);
JLabel prompt = new JLabel("How complex do you want the circle to be?");
ImageIcon image;

Circle p = new Circle(1);
int boxindex = 0;

public CircleDrawer(){
    image = new ImageIcon(p.getImage());
    box.setSelectedIndex(boxindex);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(new JLabel(image));
    add(prompt);
    add(box);
    pack();
    setSize(851, 950);
    setTitle("Circle Drawer");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    box.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == box){
        boxindex = box.getSelectedIndex();
        p.setComplexity(optionsNum[boxindex]);
        image = new ImageIcon(p.getImage());
        add(new JLabel(image));
        validate();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CircleDrawer f = new CircleDrawer();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Basically, I have this code. It references a class called `Circle`, which calculates some points on the outer edge of a circle and draws them using a `paintComponent`. In this class, there is a method called `getImage`, which takes what the `paintComponent` method drew and puts it into a BufferedImage.

```
public BufferedImage getImage() {

    BufferedImage hello = new BufferedImage(805, 805, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = hello.getGraphics();
    paintComponent( g );

    return hello;
}
```

Like so.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way for it to completely re-draw the `JFrame`. I've tried clearing the `JFrame` within the `actionPerformed` method using `removeAll()` and then COMPLETELY setting up the frame all over again (`add` all of the components, `pack`, `setSize`, `setTitle`, etc) and then `repaint`, `revalidate`, or just `validate` it.

If I simply have it `add` the image and then `validate` it, I can see the image being updated, but it's just getting tacked on at the end of the `JFrame` (just like I would expect it to using a `FlowLayout`) but that's not the behavior I need. It just shows that it is sort of working.

My question is this: How do I make it re-draw the `JFrame` when the user changes options inside of the `JComboBox`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
Graphics g = hello.getGraphics();
paintComponent( g );
```

Don't use getGraphics() and never invoke paintComponent() directly. Swing will invoke the proper painting methods are required.

```
 add(new JLabel(image));
 validate();
```

When you add (remove) components from a visible GUI the general structure of the code is:

```
add(...);
revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
repaint(); to repaint the components
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. What do I use other than getGraphics?

In my mind, I shouldn't have to add/remove components, because I'm changing the variable that the component is inside of with `image = new ImageIcon(p.getImage());`, but when I attempt to `revalidate`/`repaint`, nothing happens.

Comment: `What do I use other than getGraphics?` - you have `setter` methods on your component to change a property of the component. Then inside the setter method you invoke revalidate() and repaint(). `I shouldn't have to add/remove components` - totally agree, but you posted code shows that you are adding a component so I just explained the proper way to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have to use `getGraphics`. Unless there's some way to make `paintComponent`s follow layouts.. somebody told me that the only way to do so was to paint to a `BufferedImage` and when I searched how to do that I was told to use `getGraphics`. I can't call f.repaint() from within the `actionPerformed` method, only `repaint()`. I'm pretty confused at this point. Haha.

Comment: Yes you do need to use getGraphics() to draw on a BufferedImage. I guess the paintComponent() code confused me. To be honest I really can't tell exactly what you a trying to do with the random code you posted. Maybe [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) will help with your confusion. It give two complete examples showing different ways to do custom painting.